# Using Multiple Repsitory In ViewModel Is Bad Practice?

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

```
class HomeViewModel(
      private val employeeRepository: EmployeeRepository,
      private val localBodiesRepository: LocalBodiesRepository
) : ViewModel() {

}
```

I want to use both data's in my home activity it is a good practice or not if it is bad then what is the best practice?

Comment: I don't think this is a bad practice .Since both your repositories act upon different Entities, it makes sense to use 2 different repository

Comment: i think this question is based on opinion, i don't think there's anything particularly bad on using two repositories or making a single one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having multiple repositories is not a bad practice. It is even a good practice if repositories contains non related stuff. Yours example looks like repositories have disjoint data so it is cool to have it separated.

Answer (score 0):

As @p.mathew13 said, this is not a bad practice. Look at the view models in Google's sunflower sample from [here](https://github.com/android/sunflower).